# Hashing Algorithm Equality in zk-SNARK

Tags: solidity, blockchain, cpp-ethereum, zksnark, zero-knowledge

I am looking to implement the zk-SNARK capabilities of Ethereum to allow a user to prove that they have all the components required ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') to create a publicly known hash 'x'. My general problem can be defined as:

```
def main(x):
    sha3(a, b, c, d) == x
    return 1
```

I understand that there are two options to use when it comes to converting this general form program into a QAP and subsequent verification: ZoKrates (https://github.com/JacobEberhardt/ZoKrates) and libsnark (https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark).

Would anyone be able to help in guiding me through the steps to convert this into a workable piece of code:

1. Constructing the circuit either using ZoKrates or libsnark
2. Generating the proving and verifying key
3. Generating proofs
4. Verify the proof in Solidity

The documentation / practical examples are fairly limited so will appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: Just FYI, libsnark has a built in SHA256 gadget, but no SHA3 gadget so you may want to consider sha256 as the hash.

Comment: I see, very helpful! Have you used this before?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have any public code to demonstrate it, unfortunately. I can say that it is very helpful to walk through the ZoKrates code to see how libsnark is translated to Solidity, then duplicate that yourself

Comment: This should be reopened, since there are concrete tutorials & solutions to this now (at least with SHA256)